# What are the different ways you can subscribe to a notification from MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Please consider the code below. It works as expected - the MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification notification is being sent and the ClosePlayer method is called.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.MediaPlayer;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

public partial class PlayerViewController : MPMoviePlayerController
{
    public PlayerViewController() : base()
    {
        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver("MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification", this.ClosePlayer);
    }

    private void ClosePlayer(NSNotification notification)
    {
        // Do something..
    }
}
```

**However**, this design strikes me ass odd and **I wonder if we can do something more simple** like the below:

```
this.MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification += this.ClosePlayer;
```

It seems really unnatural to have to go through the NSNotificationCenter in order to listen to the events that are fired by the class itself. Or am I missing something?

Also - is it possible to specify the notification type (e.g. - MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification) in any way other than a hard-coded string?

Thank you in advance :)

DISCLAIMER: I am a total noob in MonoTouch and having a .NET background some things feel quite strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just accidentally found out that there is a static property on MPMoviePlayerController that can be used:

```
MPMoviePlayerController.Notifications.ObserveDidExitFullscreen(this.ClosePlayer);
```